# Being able to run java application on different computers without JDK

Tags: jar, exe, java

How can I send my java application to a friend without having to send the entire project and being dependent on him having JDK? I'm aware of the .jar-file's existence, but I don't know how to proceed. I would like to be able to just send him the .jar-file or an executable file.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you send the JAR, he dows not need to have the JDK; he just needs the JRE (the program at java.com)

Comment: If you work with NetBeans, when you "build" your project, a `dist` folder is generated, and your "packed" app is stored there. You can send the contents of this folder. Read the "readme" file in that folder.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Or are you doing it all by hand?

Comment: Thank you @Barranka, using the dist folder works somewhat like I wanted. I'm using NetBeans as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did what @Barranka said regarding the dist folder, didn't know that worked until I read the readme file as @Barranka suggested.

So to quote what @Barranka said:

> If you work with NetBeans, when you "build" your project, a dist
>   folder is generated, and your "packed" app is stored there. You can
>   send the contents of this folder. Read the "readme" file in that
>   folder. – Barranka

Comment: Your friend still have to download a JRE if it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Compile it to native code using a compiler such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java

Also, he doesn't need the JDK, just the JRE.

Comment: GCJ is a dead project and moreover it does not support all Java features such as AWT and Swing

Comment: So consider the use of Excelsior jet, but it is overkill for just not have to download a JRE :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the JAR file alone provided your program does not depend on other libraries. Assuming that there is a main() method and Main Class is configured in the JAR's manifest, the person can run it by Double Clicking (on windows) or use the command line

```
java -jar <jar_file_name>.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a Java application without a Java Virtual Machine, so you need one.
Your friend has to download a JRE/JDK, or you can provide it with your application directly as it (the JRE and your project in an archive) or provide it as a native compile code using GCJ or Excelsior Jet which will compile your application and a JRE.

As you can see the is no solution for your question, but there is one for your problem : ask your friend to download a JRE.